# HTML select is getting values from backend---how to know that when select gets populated, which event is triggered

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have a html SELECT that is getting populated from backend. How will I know that it gets its value from backend. Which event is triggered when SELECT is populated with values from backend ?

I am not talking about selecting between options of SELECT. It is just the total options values coming from backend.

Comment: _How_ are you populating it? _“Which event is triggered when SELECT is populated with values from backend ?”_ - this is basically unanswerable, until you show us what you are actually doing. (But there is no specific event for “select field got an option added to it” to begin with, at most you will probably be able to get something with a MutationObserver.)

Comment: That solved my issue @CBroe. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If the values are coming from the backend after the page has loaded you probably sent an ajax request or received a socket message, but either way you can use the callback of the request to determine that the options have been set